# Can i write some bash command pipeline that reads kafka topic, deserializes protobuf contents and writes it to terminal?

Tags: apache-kafka, protocol-buffers

I have a topic with messages serialized to protobuf. 
I have a .proto file with contract, and i want to write something similar to

```
read-kafka brokerAddress topicName startOffset | deserialize-proto myContract.proto
```

and have some text representation of messages dumped to terminal.

Maybe someone knows easiest way to do something similar to what i want ?

Comment: `protoc --decode yourExpectedMessageType myContract.proto < theinputfile` ? (can't remember off-hand; it might be `--decode=yourExpectedMessageType`)

Comment: Use kafkacat to read from the kafkatopic, it supports piping to the next step

Answer (score 1):

You can read you message (using flag `--property line.separator=''` to avoid separating lines in the data) and pass the output to the binary `protoc`

```
kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server $YOU_KAFKA_BROKERS --topic $YOU_TOPIC --from-beginning --max-messages 1 --property line.separator='' | protoc --decode=you.proto.package.Message you/proto/path.proto
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of [milena](https://github.com/VanceLongwill/milena), which does exactly this. It's a small CLI for working with protobuf Kafka messages that decodes protobuf to line delimited json.